# cv::Erode error with binary cv::mat

Tags: c++, opencv

So I'm trying to **erode a binary matrix**.
I create the matrix using this code:

```
cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros( IMG->width, IMG->height, CV_8U );

for( auto i = 0 ; i < IMG->width ; i++)
{
    for ( auto j = 0 ; j < IMG->height ; j++)
    {
        if(  cv::pointPolygonTest(cv::Mat(contour),cv::Point(i,j),true) < 0 )
        {
            tmp.at<double>(i,j) = 255;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the source picture I'm using:

[image: http://snag.gy/ZZzhw.jpg]

And this what I get with my loop (it's the tmp matrix):

[image: http://snag.gy/lhuR7.jpg]

So after I'm trying to erode the picture using this code:

```
int erosion_elem = 1;
int erosion_size = 8;


int erosion_type;
if( erosion_elem == 0 ){ erosion_type = MORPH_RECT; }
else if( erosion_elem == 1 ){ erosion_type = MORPH_CROSS; }
else if( erosion_elem == 2) { erosion_type = MORPH_ELLIPSE; }

Mat element = getStructuringElement( erosion_type,
                                   Size( 2*erosion_size + 1, 2*erosion_size+1 ),
                                   Point( erosion_size, erosion_size ) );

/// Apply the erosion operation
erode( binary, erosion_dst, element );`
```

So it compiles well but I get an exception on this line:

```
erode( binary, erosion_dst, element );`
```

It says it's an **unsupported data type**.
Does anyone have an idea why do I get this exception?

I tried to change the data type of the matrix tmp but I have the same error.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your binary image is stored with CV_8U (unsigned char), can you try
`tmp.at<unsigned char>(i,j) = 255;` to fill your tmp Mat ?

Comment: @Marcassin Yeah it works thank you !
I changed the data type of my matrix yesterday and i just forgot to change it in my filling.
I feel so dumb !

Thank you again !

Comment: @Sherokan accept the answer below to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary image pixels are stored as `unsigned char` (CV_8U -> on 8bits -> 1 byte),
you should store your pixels' value as `unsigned char` too

```
cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros( IMG->width, IMG->height, CV_8U );

for( auto i = 0 ; i < IMG->width ; i++)
{
    for ( auto j = 0 ; j < IMG->height ; j++)
    {
        if(  cv::pointPolygonTest(cv::Mat(contour),cv::Point(i,j),true) < 0 )
        {
            tmp.at<unsigned char>(i,j) = 255;
        }
    }

}
```

(made answer from comment)